# If the subject changes its number within a sentence but it's the same thing after all, how do I deal with this kind of ‘plurality’?

Tags: grammatical-number

Terminology clarification first. Let's say, *plurality* herein means *the quality of being plural; the state of being plural or not*, which is not the dictionary definition. I couldn't find another appropriate term for it. Well, *grammatical numerity*? Hmm.

---

In this sentence, the number (*plurality*) of the subject changes at the middle of the sentence. The subject was singular, but soon becomes plural.

> It's split into two and **merges/merge** back into one a hundred times.

We can also think of an inverted version of it. The subject was plural, but soon becomes singular.

> The two are merged into one and **(are)/is** split back into two a hundred times.

---

How do I deal with this kind of *plurality*? What should I assume its *plurality* is? Do I have to break it down into two or more sentences?

Comment: When in doubt, mumble.

Comment: Since you used the perfect in the first part of the sentence, the correct form to use would be the past participle, which is invariant for number anyway: “It's split into two and **merged** back into one a hundred times.”

Comment: @sumelic Thank you for your comment. You're right, the `merged` one would be the best one. But I think my sentences, which contain intransitive use of `merge`, are technically not _incorrect_, though they're not the best. Please take them as just example sentences for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either make the verb agree with the stated subject, or introduce a new pronoun for it.

So either:

> It's split into two and merges back into one a hundred times.

or

> It's split into two and they merge back into one a hundred times.

(Probably the former option, because it works better with the repetitiveness of the action.)

Likewise:

> The two are merged into one and split back into two a hundred times. (I agree with @sumelic that the participle helps here.)

or

> The two are merged into one and that is split back into two a hundred times.

Also, I didn't do it here, but I would probably always use a comma before the phrase *a hundred times* in these examples.

Comment: Yes, the cardinality changes and therefore new terms must be introduced.